# A build only device cannot be used to run this target

Tags: ios, xcode

No supported iOS devices are available. Connect a device to run your application or choose a simulated device as the destination.

I have tried to run but not succeeded.

Answer (score 1):

Select a simulator to run the application. You can do this here:
[image]